# Why does a call to bindec($val) not return the same result as hexdec(bin2hex($val))?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$val = fread($fp,1);
echo 'bindec: '.bindec($val)."\n";
echo 'bin2hex: '.bin2hex($val)."\n";
echo 'bin2hex/hexdec: '.hexdec(bin2hex($val))."\n";
?>
```

The byte being read appears in my hex editor as `0F`. My output looks like this:

```
bindec: 0
bin2hex: 0f
bin2hex/hexdec: 15
```

My question is, why is `bindec` returning `0`? Surely it should return `15`?

Comment: Did you see the warning on PHP docs about the argument to `bindec` and if isn't a string, that it may result in "unexpected results"? Can you `var_dump($val)`? Docs: http://us2.php.net/bindec

Comment: I did, and I checked the doc page for `fread`, which says it returns a string... I think that's probably where my confusion is arising from. `bin2hex` and `hexdec` both say they accept strings too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) function instead of `bindec()` in the first line. `bindec()` requires an input string containing only `1` or `0` like "110101". it does not take "real" binary data as input.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, misunderstood what your issue was :P

Bindec expends an actual string of binary, and you are giving it a normal number.